# Subquery bringing different totals than query by iteself

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm working on learning subqueries instead  of using Lookups in SSRS.

I've created a query that lists the total refunded fees for each store then built a subquery that aggregates the total refunded fees for all stores per month. When I run the subquery by itself, it lists a certain amount, but i add it to the main query, it lists different amounts for each store. For example

```
Store    Branch_Sum    Month_Sum     Month
1           325         750           1/1/2016 
2           75          1100           1/1/2016
3           525          850          1/1/2016
```

Each month's sum should all be the same, while the branch-sum should be different and add up to the month_sum. This works when the queries are separate, but now when I bring them together.

```
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS BRANCH_SUM, SUM(AggTots.POSTMONTHSUM) AS MonthSum,
CASE WHEN FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 101 AND 199 THEN 1 
WHEN FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 201 AND 299 THEN 2 
WHEN FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 301 AND 399 THEN 3 
ELSE 'OTHER' END AS Branch,
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, FEE_LOG.ENTRY_DATE), 0) AS PostMonth
FROM FEE_LOG

Inner JOIN (
SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) AS POSTMONTHSUM, MEMBER_NBR AS MEM,
DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, FEE_LOG.ENTRY_DATE), 0) AS PostMonth
FROM FEE_LOG
WHERE FOCUS_TELLER_ID < 4000
AND AMOUNT > 0
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, FEE_LOG.ENTRY_DATE), 0), Member_NBR
)AggTots on FEE_LOG.MEMBER_NBR=AggTots.MEM




WHERE FOCUS_TELLER_ID < 4000
AND AMOUNT > 0
GROUP BY CASE WHEN FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 101 AND 199 THEN 1 
WHEN FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 201 AND 299 THEN 2 
WHEN FOCUS_TELLER_ID BETWEEN 301 AND 399 THEN 3 
ELSE 'OTHER' END, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, FEE_LOG.ENTRY_DATE), 0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Good catch. I'm not, I selected the wrong tag by accident.

Comment: 1. Execute each part of the query independently, and then without aggregating and you will see the error.  If you are grouping by `member_nbr` and `PostMonth` in the subquery but not joining on those, you will have a cardinality violation.  Also, you will either need to include `POSTMONTHSUM` in your outer query group by, or take the MAX of the value. 2. You can do this more directly with a windowing function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15